# How do I use checkboxfor htmlhelper with a bool property of class that is a property of my viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I thinks my question will be best understood with the example below.

```
public Class1 
{
    public bool SomeProperty1 {get;set;}
    public string SomeProperty2 {get;set;}
}

public Class2
{
    //bool property in which i want to use the checkboxfor
    public List<Class1> SomeProperty3 {get;set;} 

    public string SomeProperty4 {get;set;}
}

@model Class2

@Html.Textboxfor(SomeProperty4)...
.
.
.
@foreach(var x in SomeProperty3)
{
    <td>Html.Checkboxfor(model=>x.SomeProperty1...) </td>
    //How?
}
```

I also cant figure out how to add a disabled property to the html element.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  You are already using `Checkboxfor`, so is your question only aimed at figuring out how to make it disabled?

Comment: First you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)). But even if your generate your form controls correctly, adding the disabled attribute means that the value of `SomeProperty1` will always be `false` when you submit your form (since  disabled controls do not submit a value). Why are you wanting a disabled checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can using html attributes as below.

`Html.Checkboxfor(model=>x.SomeProperty1,new {@disabled="diasbled"})`

Comment: Works! Good stuff

Comment: This would just mean that even if the checkbox is initially checked, the value of the property would be `false` when submitted, making it pointless.